# How can I disable some functionality only if web on Flutter app?

Tags: flutter, dart, web, flutter-web

I see that up today flutter has a beta [**web support**](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/web). But if I have some view or in general some functionality that support only mobile devices, how can disable it only when I build for the web? is it possible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

if (kIsWeb) {
  // running on the web!
} else {
  // NOT running on the web! You can check for additional platforms here.
}
```

Also if you want to check for inside widget and not show mobile widget

```
child: kIsWeb ? Container():<Mobile Widget>
```

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/kIsWeb-constant.html